# Need help to retrieve all the data to listview

Tags: java, php, android-studio, listview, android-listview

I'm trying to make an android application that can read data from a database. but when I try to display some rows in the listview, only the bottom row of the code that I make is displayed.

this is my code for MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
        getJSON("http://192.168.137.234/librenms/getdata.php");

    }

    private void getJSON(final String urlWebService) {
        class GetJSON extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                try {
                    loadIntoListView(s);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(urlWebService);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) !=null) {
                        sb.append(json).append("\n");
                    }
                    return sb.toString().trim();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }
        GetJSON getJSON = new GetJSON();
        getJSON.execute();
    }

    private void loadIntoListView(String json) throws JSONException {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
        String[] alerts = new String[jsonArray.length()];
```

this is the part to showing the atribute on listview

```
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject object = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            alerts[i] = object.getString("Rule ID");
            alerts[i] = object.getString("Device ID");
            alerts[i] = object.getString("Time logged");
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, alerts);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

Comment: In this part: `alerts[i] = object.getString("Rule ID");` you are assigning values 3 times on the same position. Would you like to concatenate Rule ID, Device ID and Time logged?

Comment: i need to put Rule ID, Devcie ID, and time logged to listview. but in my listview only showing 1 row. https://imgur.com/UDsxHat you can see my screenshot for my app here.

Comment: To show each row (from your database) as independent object in your app you must use Recyclerview instead listview. If you just want to show your data in each row of your listview you must to concatenate them.

Comment: can i know how to concatenate them ? i'm totally newbie for android studio.

Comment: Try replacing that 3 code lines: `alerts[i]...` with: `alerts[i] = object.getString("Rule ID")+" "+object.getString("Device ID")+" "+object.getString("Time logged")`;

Comment: it works, thanks @CristianoDeVinni